# UITableView populated but not displaying data or rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I know this particular question has been asked and answered previously in SO but cross checked those answers and still not able to fix this issue. Can be a silly mistake but unable to nail it.

Cross checked :
Cell Identifierid 
datasource and delegate added through Interface builder

Code :

```
var sensorFields = [Sensor]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        readParseDataFromCSV(file: "csvFile")

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print(self.sensorFields.count)// has count 120
        return self.sensorFields.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SensorTableCell") as! SensorTableViewCell

        cell.lblSensorName.text = sensorFields[indexPath.row].labelName
        cell.lblSensorValue.text = sensorFields[indexPath.row].labelValue

        print(sensorFields[indexPath.row].labelName) // doesn't seem to enter to this code block
        print(sensorFields[indexPath.row].labelValue)

        return cell
    }

    func readParseDataFromCSV(file:String){
        let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "csv")!

        do {
            let csv = try CSV(contentsOfURL: filepath)
            let rows = csv.rows

            for row in rows{

                let sensorlblName = row["data column 1"]
                let sensorlblValue = row["data column 2"]
                let sensor = Sensor(labelName: sensorlblName!, labelValue: sensorlblValue!)

                sensorFields.append(sensor)

            }


        } catch {

            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }

class SensorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblSensorName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSensorValue: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Is there anything missed out , using other tableviews in the app already which is working perfectly apart from this one.
Using Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3.0

Edit :

Added reloadData()

Seems like 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}

is not firing too.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: set the delegate for the tableView to self or did you drag the tableView to file Owner and set the dataSource and Delegate

Comment: Try to reload tableView after your `for loop` inside `readParseDataFromCSV` method.

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan, I have dragged tableview to the Viewcontroller and set datasource, delegate both

Comment: You just need to reload your table view after parsing CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just appending data to your `sensorFields` array has no impact on the cells displayed in your `tableView`.

You need to call `reloadData` on the `tableView` so it knows the data did change and repopulates the cells with the new data.

```
for row in rows {

    let sensorlblName = row["data column 1"]
    let sensorlblValue = row["data column 2"]
    let sensor = Sensor(labelName: sensorlblName!, labelValue: sensorlblValue!)

    sensorFields.append(sensor)

}

tableView.reloadData()
```

I would also prefer

```
// newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered
// Swift 2
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
// Swift 3
func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

to

```
// Used by the delegate to acquire an already allocated cell, in lieu of allocating a new one.
// Swift 2
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?
// Swift 3
func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?
```

because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String)` does not guarantee returning a `UITableViewCell` when the cell with `identifier` was not yet allocated. (*"[...] acquire an already allocated cell, in lieu of allocating a new one."*)

**And make sure your `IBOutlets` are connected! (`lblSensorName` and `lblSensorValue`)**

Comment: Thanks . Added reloadData() but still the same.

Comment: @user2695433 please also use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` instead of `func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String)`

Comment: tried as you mentioned like , func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SensorTableCell", for: indexPath) as! SensorTableViewCell
        
        cell.lblSensorName.text = sensorFields[indexPath.row].labelName
        cell.lblSensorValue.text = sensorFields[indexPath.row].labelValue
        
        print("tableview reached")
            
        return cell
    } but still data not showing up.

Comment: @user2695433 with what effect? now cells? cells but no content in the labels? did you connect your outlets? (lblSensorName & lblSensorValue)

Comment: yes, the outlets  are connected already. code is now pasted in the question for your perusal

Comment: shows no effect. no trace of cells . Also , worth mentioning that had placed a print statement to check whether the code is executing but not firing func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

Comment: Can you please share a code stub which goes inside func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }

Comment: @user2695433 you just need to use the `indexPath` you get from `cellForRowAt indexPath`

Comment: tried like  without luck , func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SensorTableCell", for: indexPath) as! SensorTableViewCell
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SensorTableViewCell
        
        cell.lblSensorName.text = sensorFields[indexPath.row].labelName
        cell.lblSensorValue.text = sensorFields[indexPath.row].labelValue
        
        print("tableview reached")
            
        return cell
    }

Comment: @user2695433 if `cellForRowAt indexPath` is not called your `dataSource` is not set. but since your wrote that you have set it in IB you are doomed. :D

Comment: you are right. now I even removed IB outlets for Datasource and Delegate and added to code. Still I 'm doomed :D . wondering what might causing this

Comment: finally managed to get it working. I had removed all the outlet references and added once again. Restarted XCode. finally appears. :D thanks mate

Comment: @user2695433 Oh.. well.. :D

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SensorTableCell") as UITableViewCell!
    if !cell {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style:.Default, reuseIdentifier: "SensorTableCell")
    }

}
```

Comment: tried but having error "Value of type UITableViewcCell has no member lblName and lblValue"

Comment: you need to change type of cell  chnege this line :var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SensorTableCell") as SensorTableViewCell

Comment: The question is tagged Swift 3. This is not Swift 3 code.

Comment: did you check in swift @rmaddy.

Comment: @KKRocks I have no idea what your response means.

Comment: @KKRocks No, it's not. Look at the Swift 3 documentation for `UITableViewDataSource`. Look at the code in the question. Now look at your answer. Your code is Swift 2, not Swift 3.